# Using ES6 arrow functions in AngularJS html templates

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

is there a posibility to use ES6 arrow functions directly in AngularJS html tamplates like this ?

```
<div ng-if="results.filter(e => e.ext == 'xml').length > 0">Text</div>
```

'result' is a list of objects with 'ext' as property.
Until now I've used lodash and it works perfectly:

```
<div ng-if="_.filter(results, { ext : 'xml' }).length > 0">Text</div>
```

but will change to ES6 if possible...

Has anybody experience with that or some hints or maybe better ideas ?

Comment: You can do that, angular evaluates any js expression in `ng-if` directive, but you shouldn't do that. Because there are many versions of browsers that do not support ES6.

Comment: @alexmac This is AngularJS and Expressions in AngularJS have limitations. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions).

Comment: Plenty of browsers support native ES6 now, go crazy with it.  https://caniuse.com/#search=es6

Answer (score 2):

The [ng-if directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) evaluates an [AngularJS Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) and function declarations are not allowed.

From the Docs:

> ## AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions
>
> AngularJS expressions are like JavaScript expressions with the following differences:
>
> - **No Function Declarations:** You cannot declare functions in an AngularJS expression, even inside `ng-init` directive.
>
> **If you want to run more complex JavaScript code, you should make it a controller method** and call the method from your view. If you want to `eval()` an AngularJS expression yourself, use the [`$eval()` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval).
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Comment: To clarify on calling eval() in an AngularJS expression, you can only call eval() from within an Expression, to evaluate something that itself is a valid expression. E.g. you can call $eval(expr) from the ng-if, but expr can only be a valid Angular expression defined in the controller e.g. '3*10|currency'

Answer (score 1):

No, as georgeawg has said, you can't declare functions at all inside an Expression (e.g inside an 'ng-if'). This is partly because Angular is designed to encourage any business logic to be placed in the controller, to encourage correct separation of concerns.

Angular Expressions are limited to fairly basic things like accessing properties of objects or values on the scope, and basic formatting, sorting and filtering. Any business logic definitions belong in the controller.